# How to add a button inside of datatable's cells to show detail in popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables-1.10

My question is about to datatable.js . i wanna add button inside of the datatable columns' cells to expand tetail of content cell. if i click red button a popupmodal should appear to show all list of content in datatable.js.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use fnRowCallback
https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback
```

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow,aData,iDisplayIndex,iDisplayIndexFull) {
  // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
  if ( aData[4] == "A" )
  {
    $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( ' <button type="button">Red button </button> ' );
  }
}
```

} );

Comment: A [**column.render**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) would be more uptodate :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of basic jQuery functions, it is completely possible to do this.

First of all, please check these two examples:

[Example 1](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html) and [Example 2](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

As seen in the example;

```
"columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
    } ]
```

you can add an "defaultContent" to targeted column (and it can be a button!). In this example it is the last column on the table. And you can give any functionality to this button's onclick event.

Or alternatively, you can detect row clicks like;

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
} );
```

and open a bootstrap modal like `$("#myModal").modal()` instead of,

`alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );`.